# Azure Event Grid: Deliver events if blob contains metadata

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage, azure-eventgrid

I created an event subscription for `BlobCreated` event. I'm using `Azure Functions` with an `EventGridTrigger` to receive the events. Right now, events are firing every time a new blob is created. Is it possible to create an advanced filter in the event subscription so that the events are delivered only when a blob contains metadata?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this feature is not supported in the AEG Advanced filtering, see the event schemas for Azure Blob Storage as an Event Grid source [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/event-schema-blob-storage).

As you can see in this document, there is no blob's metadata in the event data object.

Comment: Is there any way, I can find `metadata` for received BlobCreated event? Like for file created I want to get list of all metadata.

Comment: @yogendarji use the *await blob.FetchAttributesAsync()* in your EventGridTrigger function to obtain a blob's metadata, where the blob is an input binding argument of the CloudBlockBlob.

Comment: I have tried with `public static async void Runasync([EventGridTrigger] EventGridEvent eventGridEvent, [Blob("test/{name}", FileAccess.Read, Connection = "ConnectionString")] CloudBlockBlob blob, ILogger log)` but still blob is always `null`

Comment: @yogendarji, you should use for blobPath **"{data.url}"**